# How do you get the current time in milliseconds (long), in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, time

I'm looking for the equivalent to a Java `System.currentTimeMilli()`, in VB.NET.

What is the method to call? I know about Datetime.Now, but not about the actual conversion to long milliseconds.

---

More details about my specific need:

I need to manage a login expiration. So most likely when I log in, I will set a "expiration_time_milli", equal to the current time + the timeout value. Then later, if I want to check if my login is valid, I will check is "expiration_time_milli" is still superior to current time.

Comment: +1 for the more details. It's better to explain your problem & ask for [the .Net way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385853/how-do-you-get-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-long-in-vb-net/4386533#4386533), rather than look for an exact translation of a Java solution. The latter will produce code that's longer and will look a bit odd to an experienced .Net developer.

Comment: @MarkJ - yes, I wrote my initial question quickly (lack of time at this particular moment); only after I added details, seeing as the exact translation is indeed not appropriate or efficient. The given answers helped me understand the objects around all this (for example discovering the TimeLapse, with the given examples), though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's somewhat alarming to see all the answers here referring to `DateTime.Now`, which returns the *local* time (as in "in the system default time zone") - whereas `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). All the answers here should probably refer to `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.

Fortunately, somewhat after this question was asked, a much simpler approach has been made available, via `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`. So you just need:

```vb
Dim millis = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

Comment: Switching accepted answer to this one to give more visibility to the more exact/actual content. Technically I had a more specific need, but let's be honest, this is now more about the generic question asked in the title than about my personal case from a decade ago (oh my)

Answer (score 14):

Get the difference between the current time and the time origin, use the `TotalMilliseconds` property to get time span as milliseconds, and cast it to long.

```
DirectCast((Datetime.Now - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds, Int64)
```

Comment: If the the code will be called frequently I would probably create a static (`Shared` in VB) variable to hold the `New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)` value since it is, well, static. No need to recreate the object for each call.

Comment: Or CLng((Datetime.Now - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds)

Comment: `DateTime.Now` provides the time in the system local time zone; using the `Ticks` value of that is *not* equivalent to `System.currentTimeMillis()` which returns the elapsed time since the Unix epoch - i.e. it's *not* sensitive to the system time zone. Using `DateTime.UtcNow` would be better, but these days there's a simpler alternative - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
(DateTime.Now-new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Btw, just guessing by your question what you could be more useful to you might be

```
DateTime.UtcNow
```

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow` would be the correct approach here, rather than DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 4):

For information, my personal case was fixed with another way, without getting the exact same value as a System.currentTimeMilli():

```
Dim loginExpirationDate As Date

'...

'Checking code:
If (loginExpirationDate < DateTime.Now) Then
    reconnect()
End If

'update the expiration date
loginExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(timeoutMilli)
```

Comment: Note that using `DateTime.Now` will probably mess things up around time zone offset transitions (e.g. daylight saving time changes).

Answer (score 1):

You may also use this value, if you are looking for just a unique number.
**DateTime.Now.Ticks**

See Details
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: He does not mention anything about looking for an unique number in the question.

Comment: That's exactly what I came here looking for, thanks.

Comment: Millis since 1st Jan 0001
Dim millisNow = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / 10000

Comment: In my case, very quick successive calls to DateTime.Now.Ticks still yielded the same number, but I compensated with a wrapper function that adds 1 if it returns <= the last time.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` provides the time in the system local time zone; using the `Ticks` value of that is *not* equivalent to `System.currentTimeMillis()` which returns the elapsed time since the Unix epoch - i.e. it's *not* sensitive to the system time zone. Using `DateTime.UtcNow` would be better, but these days there's a simpler alternative - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim myTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    MessageBox.Show(myTime.Millisecond)
```

Comment: **Wrong sorry!** `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` is just the millisecs since last second rollover, so is not a correct answer (and goes horribly wrong in timing loops as I found out the hard way).

Comment: `DateTime.Now` provides the time in the system local time zone; using the `Ticks` value of that is *not* equivalent to `System.currentTimeMillis()` which returns the elapsed time since the Unix epoch - i.e. it's *not* sensitive to the system time zone. Using `DateTime.UtcNow` would be better (although www-0av-Com's point still stands), but these days there's a simpler alternative - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply `DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000`

The is **the most direct answer** to the simple question asked, and is a proven direct substitute to Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` assuming it is required to measure elapsed time (in that it runs from Jan 1, 0001, whereas Java runs from Jan 1 1970).

Notes:

- DateTime.Now.Ticks is 10,000 ticks per millisec, but tests show it has a resolution of approx 1ms anyway.
- Nb: `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` is just the millisecs since last second rollover, so is not useful in most timing
  measurements.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Ticks` doesn't give an elapsed time since any fixed epoch, due to it being in *local* time. When clocks go back due to a daylight saving time change for example, `DateTime.Now.Ticks` will give a lower number than before. Compare that with `System.currentTimeMillis()` which gives an elapsed time since the Unix epoch, which is a fixed instant in time. Using `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`, as well as showing how to offset it to the Unix epoch and scale it to miilseconds, would be a *true* direct substitute for `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score -1):

To get current Date and Time with Milliseconds I have used

```
Dim Time1 as String = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")*
```

The `.fff tt` will give you the milliseconds with current date and time.

Comment: That's not the result in milliseconds that the OP wants - they want "the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch", as returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Java.