# How do I run a sub a certain amount of times a second until running = false?

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6

I'm using visual basic as I will be studying it soon in college and I was wondering how could I run a sub a certain amount of times a second I have tried using Do Loop whilst calling the function inside the Loop

```
Do
    GameLoop()
Loop Until running = false
```

I've also tried using a while loop, any help would be great :D

Comment: use a timer to call the event.  calculate the `Interval` based on that `certain amount of times`

Comment: How exact do you need to be, because loops per second isn't necessarily something you can specify accurately. This is mostly because of the potential duration of a loop being greater than the (single loop consumption time * loops per second). Then you have to factor in multi-threading and thread wait time.

Comment: You have three different languages tagged on your question: please pick one

Comment: VBA and VB6 don't support multithreading. Please edit your post to only include the relevant language tag(s). Thanks!

Comment: You can use threads in VB6 but it isn't pretty: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1287

Comment: I agree with @paul, making a loop execute against time is a hard matter, but another loop approach you can attempt is a `For` loop which allows a certain amount of executions before completion.

Answer (score 0):

If getting the loop into hundredths of a second is acceptable, then the following would work.

```
Dim Start As Variant
Do
  Start = Timer

  GameLoop

  Do While (Timer - Start < 0.01)
   DoEvents
  Loop
Loop Until running = False
```

If more precision is needed then replace the timer with:  [How to get time elapsed in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073269/how-to-get-time-elapsed-in-milliseconds)

If the GameLoop is too slow, then it will run full-speed; otherwise it will run at the desired Loops per second.

DoEvents could be removed if not needed, or you don't like it's event jumbling side effects.

Note this is VB6 code, for the VB.Net millisecond timer check out: [How do you get the current time in milliseconds (long), in VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385853/how-do-you-get-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-long-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

Place another loop inside your loop.

In this inner loop you wait for the remaining time, and if there is no time left you continue.

I used the GetTickCount API for this which uses milliseconds as its input althought its accuracy depends on the resolution of the cpu clock

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private mblnRun As Boolean

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  StartLoop
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  StopLoop
End Sub

Private Sub StartLoop()
  Dim lngStart As Long
  mblnRun = True
  Do While mblnRun
    'store start time
    lngStart = GetTickCount
    'do your actions
    DoSomething
    'wait for the remaining time
    Do While GetTickCount < lngStart + 2000
      'wait until 2 seconds are passed since the start of this loop cycle
      DoEvents
    Loop
  Loop
End Sub

Private Sub StopLoop()
  mblnRun = False
  Caption = "Stopped : " & CStr(Now)
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething()
  Caption = "Running : " & CStr(Now)
End Sub
```

As long as `mblnRun` is `True` the loop keeps running